# Plotly Python: sort bar descending with multiple subplots

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart

I have a 4 chart subplot in Python that I am using to help calculate model selection. The models are regression models, so I am using a mix of histograms (predictions x actuals) and bar charts (train, test, cv scores). My code is as follows:

```
fig = make_subplots(3,2, specs=[[{'colspan':2}, None],
                                 [{'colspan':2}, None],
                                [{'type':'xy'}, {'type':'xy'}]
                               ],
                   subplot_titles=('Log of Predictions and Actuals','Test and Train Scores','Test Score','Cross Validation'))

fig.add_histogram(x=np.log(y_test), name='Actuals', xbins={'size':0.1},
                 row=1,col=1)
fig.add_histogram(x=np.log(preds), name='Predictions', xbins={'size':0.1},
                 row=1,col=1),

for score in ['test','train']:
    fig.add_bar(x=scores_kf_df.T.index,y=scores_kf_df.T[str(score)], name=score, row=2, col=1)
    
for score in ['test']:
    fig.add_bar(x=scores_kf_df.T.index,y=scores_kf_df.T[str(score)], name=score, row=3, col=1)

for score in ['cv']:
    fig.add_bar(x=scores_kf_df.T.index,y=scores_kf_df.T[str(score)], name=score, row=3, col=2)

fig.update_layout({'height':1200,'width':800,
                  'title':{'text':'Accuracy Metrics of Each Model','x':0.5, 'font':{'size':28}},
                  'xaxis':{'categoryorder':'total descending'}})
```

My output is as follows:
[image: Plotly subplots]

My question is, how do I make the bottom three bar charts so that they are in line the way bar charts should be? I would like to sort by descending for each of these, but the only thing I can find is fig.update_layout({‘xaxis’:‘total descending’}), which doesn’t work.

How do I sort by descending when it comes to multiple subplots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out - simple solution of reordering the dataframe prior to plotting.

```
for score in scores_kf_df.T.columns:
    df_sorted = scores_kf_df.T.sort_values(by=score, ascending=False)
    fig.add_bar(x=df_sorted.index,y=df_sorted[str(score)], name=score, row=1, col=1)
```

df_sorted here is just all values sorted by descending.